# Users not getting ip when connected through wifi,but wired connection getting ip in ddwrt router

Tags: wifi, router

I am having **DD-WRT v24-sp2(05/08/11)** running on **Asus RT n 13 u B1** router,with dhcp on.

But users not able to connect through wifi...its showing obtaining ip address and disconnects there after.

Wired Devices are getting ip address and able to access internet.Wifi was working till yesterday,but all of a sudden it stopped working.

on the **ddwrt controlpanel>system information**
under **Wireless Clients** mac address of clients that are trying to connect are appearing but  soon it disappears.
but no such issue with wired clients.

Can any one please help me in fixing this..

**Under the Wireless tab :**

> Received (RX)14146 OK, **70 errors**
>
> Transmitted (TX)4186 OK, no error

Comment: When you say "disconnects there after", what precisely do you mean? What exactly happens when you try to connect?

Comment: How many client devices do you have?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz When a client tries to connect,on the client side its showing obtaining ip address,in the mean time on the router status page under wireless clients;its showing their mac-address for a couple of seconds and clearing that.

Comment: @Volodymyr 15 PC which are wired and almost same no of mobile phones,Problem occurs when mobile tries to connect through wifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, as you said, you made no changes on the router, the issue may be due to IP-address exhaustion.

Default Lease Time on DD-WRT is 1440 mins, i.e. 24H.

Try running *"ipconfig /release"* & *"ipconfig /renew"* on a client machine with Wi-Fi enabled.

View active IP-address leases on Status tab >  LAN tab.

If this is the case, change lease time to a lower value on general page.

Comment: actually all the wireless devices are mobile phones.

Comment: Dont know whether this is the reason,it worked when i changed 1440 mins to 14 mins.

Comment: Problem appeared again...this time changing that variable didnt make any difference.

Comment: Try to restart your router. Leases will be dropped.

Comment: unfortunately restarting router also didnt fix... switching  router off for couple of minutes solved it for now.